# Asus Zenfone 5 not detected by computer

Tags: android, mobile

I have an Asus Zenfone 5. I enabled USB debugging but on conneсting my phone to the computer, it shows no Android device could be detected. What can I do?

Comment: Which program are you using and what have you tried so far? I guess you are having problems with the ADB connection of either Android Studio or Eclipse with ADT but you need to provide further pieces of information.

Comment: Maybe you're missing the Asus USB drivers. You may need to install the USB drivers first, before you can successfully connected to your Asus Zenfone 5.

Comment: I had similar issue. I had to disable developer mode and re-enabled in order to be able to use USB connection.

Answer (score 8):

This should solve your problem.

1. Download the Asus USB Driver for Zenfone 5 [***here***](http://www.asus.com/support/Download/39/1/0/2/32/)
2. Extract the rar file
3. Go to your Device Manager if you're on Windows *(Make sure you've connected your phone to your computer)*
4. Choose update driver then browse the path to where the extracted rar file is. It should prompt something on your phone, just accept it
5. Try it on your IDE, just select run configurations

Comment: I tried to browse but its not detecting driver files. Can you suggest in details that what folder we have to select from extracted zip folder?

Comment: For example, I've extracted mine in the downloads folder.  
**C:\Users\username\Downloads\ASUS_Android_USB_drivers_for_Windows_20140325\Windows_XP_VISTA_7_8_8.1**    
that will be the path then it should install/update automatically

Comment: How to do that in Linux (Mint 13), without using wine??

Answer (score 7):

Settings > Storage > Click the USB Icon at the upper right corner > Check your choice

Comment: Thanks a lot, your one line, saved my lot of time and frustration, thanks a ton again.

Answer (score 3):

Try a different usb cable. My cable was bad. Charging was ok but did not attach the phone.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it the following way :

```
1. Go to Settings->Storage->Click the USB icon at top
2. Make sure that MTP is selected
```

Answer (score 1):

To enable USB Debugging first you need to enable Developer Options.

1. Open Zenfone Settings and scroll down and tap About.
2. Scroll down and select Software Information.
3. Under Software information you will see Build Number.
4. Tap Build Number 7 times to enable Developer Options.
5. Come back to Settings and scroll down to find Developer Options.
6. Tap on Developer Options and it will open upto give you option to enable USB Debugging

Answer (score 0):

This are the steps :

1. Download and install latest version of pclink for PC from [here](http://pclink.asus.com).
2. Make sure PCLink is running in Foreground on Asus Zenfone 5 and in settings on rightmost topmost corner click on USB icon and then check the MTP checkbox.
3. Click connect on PCLink on PC.
4. If Asus USB Driver for Zenfone 5 is properly installed on your PC.You will see 'Asus Android Device' in your Device Manager otherwise install Asus USB Driver for Zenfone 5 from [here](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=ASUS%20ZenFone%205&p=39&s=1&os=32&hashedid=96nqlxHp1VKV4Rdz) 
   then try again
5. Now you will be able to see your device online in Android Studio and screen of your device on PCLink software on your PC.

I haven't tried for eclipse but it might work for that also.

Answer (score 0):

driver Asus for Windows: http://www.asus.com/sa-en/support/Download/39/1/0/2/32/

Choose target device: `USB device`

[image]
(open image in new tab for bigger)

Answer (score 0):

Install Asus PC Link on your PC available here: https://www.asus.com/ph/support/FAQ/1007320/